# Why does conditionally rendering lead to odd animation in material autocomplete?

Tags: angular, typescript

We want to show a form with an autocomplete conditionally in Angular, e.g. when a user clicks a button the form shall be shown and the button shall become invisible (in reality our design is of course more complex). For this it seems to be most intuitive to render the components conditionally, e.g. with `@if`:

```html
@if(!showForm){
  <button (click)="showForm=true">show form</button>
} 

@if(showForm) {
  <form class="example-form">
    <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
      <mat-label>Number</mat-label>
      <!-- #docregion input -->
      <input
        type="text"
        placeholder="Pick one"
        aria-label="Number"
        matInput
        [formControl]="myControl"
        [matAutocomplete]="auto"
      />
      <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
        @for (option of options; track option) {
        <mat-option [value]="option">{{option}}</mat-option>
        }
      </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
  </
```

But this has the small imperfection that the label of the mat input moves up to the top of the input field as soon as the form gets rendered (similar to when entering something in an empty input field). For other components, e.g. an input without an autocomplete this problem doesn't occur. Here is a [stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ktmcuk?file=src%2Fexample%2Fautocomplete-simple-example.html).

After much debugging, we were able to find out that we can prevent this by simply setting `display=none` conditionally instead of hiding parts of the html with `@if`. But I'm interested to know why this is so? Is there any other way than `display=none` to avoid the problem?

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Option A

You can use the attribute `hidden` to show/hide the same way as `@if` and you will not encounter this behaviour!

```
@if(!showForm){
<button (click)="showForm=true">show form</button>
}
<form class="example-form" [hidden]="!showForm"> <!-- changed here -->
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
    <mat-label>Number</mat-label>
    <!-- #docregion input -->
    <input
      type="text"
      placeholder="Pick one"
      aria-label="Number"
      matInput
      [formControl]="myControl"
      [matAutocomplete]="auto"
    />
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      @for (option of options; track option) {
      <mat-option [value]="option">{{option}}</mat-option>
      }
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ktmcuk-mdzmrm?file=src%2Fexample%2Fautocomplete-simple-example.html,src%2Fexample%2Fautocomplete-simple-example.ts,package.json)

---

#### Option B

You can use the property [`floatLabel`](https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/api#MatFormField) to always show on top, instead of letting it hover!

#### @Input() floatLabel: FloatLabelType

> export type FloatLabelType = 'always' | 'auto';
> Whether the label should always float or float as the user types.

```
@if(!showForm){
    <button (click)="showForm=true">show form</button>
} @if(showForm) {
<form class="example-form">
  <mat-form-field class="example-full-width" [floatLabel]="'always'">
    <mat-label>Number</mat-label>
    <!-- #docregion input -->
    <input
      type="text"
      placeholder="Pick one"
      aria-label="Number"
      matInput
      [formControl]="myControl"
      [matAutocomplete]="auto"
    />
    <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete">
      @for (option of options; track option) {
      <mat-option [value]="option">{{option}}</mat-option>
      }
    </mat-autocomplete>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
}
```

Comment: The label moving up, when the formcontrol has a value, is not the default behavior, e.g. when you set `"showForm=true"` and reload the page you see that the label doesn't initially move. And also when you render the input without the autocomplete, e.g. by removing: `[matAutocomplete]="auto"` in the html of the stackblitz link, the label doesn't move. Setting the form control value to an empty string is not an option  when you want to edit an existing value. The problem is that is just looks odd and unprofessional when some labels are moving in a form and some not...

Comment: ok thank you that helps. But just for my understanding you wrote: `and you will not encounter this bug`. Does this mean you consider the mat-autocomplete behavior as bug?

Comment: @Jonathan its not a bug, my mistake spoke incorrectly